# What do these specific symbols in a Webpack loader do? Module not found error upon upgrade

Tags: css, webpack

I'm in the process of upgrading a website from Webpack1 to Weback3, and I'm having trouble translating the scss loader into the Webpack 3 format because of the following line:

```
    css?-autoprefixer&sourceMap!postcss?parser=postcss-scss!sass?sourceMap'
```

I've figured out that to translate this line to Webpack3, I need to add the "-loader" suffix to sone of the items, for exmaple "css" becomes "css-loader."

I can even get the site to compile if I take out the last-half of the line, and include only "css-loader," but the homepage styling is broken. For some reason, if I include the whole source map section, it fails to compile with error "ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'css?-autoprefixer&sourceMap'"

The original loader in Webpack 1 was:

```
     loaders: [
          {
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css?-autoprefixer&sourceMap!postcss?parser=postcss-scss!sass?sourceMap'),
            test: /\.scss$/
          },
```

In Webpack 3, I have translated it to:

```
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
       use: [require.resolve('css-loader?-autoprefixer&sourceMap!postcss-loader?parser=postcss-scss!sass-loader?sourceMap'), require.resolve('sass-loader')]
        })
      },
```

If anyone can give me some pointers on how to get around this module not found error, I would be very grateful. I've spent hours reviewing the documentation, and googling, and I can't seem to find a clear guide as to what all of the connector symbols in the line mean (`! = ? &`) or why it now returns module not found.
[image: Module not found error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols have to do with inline loaders. From the documentation:

> It's possible to specify loaders in an import statement, or any equivalent "importing" method. Separate loaders from the resource with !. Each part is resolved relative to the current directory.
>
> import Styles from 'style-loader!css-loader?modules!./styles.css';
> It's possible to overwrite any loaders in the configuration by
> prefixing the entire rule with !.
>
> Options can be passed with a query parameter, e.g. ?key=value&foo=bar,
> or a JSON object, e.g. ?{"key":"value","foo":"bar"}.

https://webpack-3.cdn.bcebos.com/concepts/loaders/#inline